# Strange system load after ~5 min of inactivity

Tags: windows

On my notebook Lenovo Z701 with Windows 10 installed I noticed a strange CPU load: after 5 min of user inactivity System process loads CPU at 30%. If I move the mouse, System process stops loading CPU. Is it a normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to energy states on your notebook or some service that is running as you go idle (file indexer?).

Try setting up a different energy profile (like High Performance) or tracking down if some service is starting to use CPU as you go idle.